# 'Discorso perifrastico' vs. 'argomentazione perifrastica'

Tags: word-usage

Curiosando su Internet ho notato che esistono relativamente molte occorrenze per 'discorso perifrastico', ma nessuna per 'argomentazione perifrastica'.

Siccome poi un 'discorso' non è un'entità concettuale molto diversa da un' 'argomentazione', mi chiedo, e chiedo, perché nessuno usa 'argomentazione perifrastica'?

Comment: Elberich, sei sicuro che esistano “relativamente molte occorrenze per 'discorso perifrastico'”? Io ne trovo 8 su Google e 12 su Google Books (e molte sono in comune), ma forse sbaglio qualcosa.

Comment: Sì, sono quelle, @dag. Non ti sembrano relativamente molte?

Answer (score 3):

L'espressione "discorso perifrastico" non è molto comune, con essa si intende un discorso che usa una o più perifrasi, ovvero dei giri di parole al posto di termini precisi.
Certo si può dire anche "argomentazione perifrastica", ma non mi sorprende che sia una espressione ancora meno comune. Se non è usata, è solo perché raramente si parla di queste cose, ed esistono espressioni più popolari e semplici, come appunto "giro di parole" per dire la stessa cosa.